# Java: Convert string to KeyEvent virtual key code?

Tags: java, regex, keyevent, keycode

I'm trying to write a method that will take a single character string and (if possible) return the [virtual key code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) it corresponds to.

For instance:

```
private static int getKeyCode(final String key) {
    if(key.length != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only support single characters");

    // Also check to see if the 'key' is (1-9)(A-Z), otherwise exception

    // How to perform the conversion?
}

// Returns KeyEvent.VK_D
MyKeyUtils.getKeyCode("D");
```

Thus, passing `MyKeyUtils.getKeyCode("blah")` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` because "blah" has 4 chars. Also, passing `MyKeyUtils.getKeyCode("@")`throws the same exception because "@" is neither a digit 0-9 or a character A - Z.

Any ideas how to do the regex check as well as the actual conversion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (key.matches("[^1-9A-Z]"))
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
```

---

[Convertion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_1) can be done using `(int) key.charAt(0)` value, because:

```
public static final int VK_0 48 
public static final int VK_1 49 
...
public static final int VK_9 57 
public static final int VK_A 65 
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Omega (+1) - please see my comment under Prince's answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: Thanks again @Omega - so Strings can't be converted to `int`s, so are you saying I should use: `Integer.parse(key)` and that will work?

Comment: You need to use `key.charAt()` before converting to an `int`.

Comment: @pnongrata - `(int) key.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Match your input against `^[0-9A-Za-z]$` or `^[\\w&&[^_]]$`

```
if(!key.matches("[0-9A-Za-z]")) 
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid input ...");
```

and

```
int code = key.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Thanks @Prince John Wesley (+1) - what about the key code conversion? Any ideas there? Thanks again!

Comment: @pnongrata: i don't understand the key code conversion. key code is merely an named variable holds ascii value of the key